# Rails: Run code before ActiveRecord model retrieval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to run code BEFORE model retrieval? I know about the **after_find** callback, but I need to run before. I'd also like it to run only ONCE per retrieval regardless of the number of records returned. Looking at the RoR source it seems the query is actually executed in **exec_queries**(or **to_a**) in **ActiveRecord::Relation**. Do/Should I override this method to add this hook?

And just in case I'm going about this all wrong, the reason I'm asking is I have an external REST API I am using to retrieve data, but it is too slow to retrieve after every page reload. I was originally using memcached, but I figured I could just use ActiveRecord to cache the data in a database so I can easily query the data and possibly join it with similar data from other REST APIs. I'd like to plug in a callback that would after a certain timeout duration, reload the data from REST before returning ActiveRecord results.

Basically I'm looking for the best way to centralize refreshing my database from another source (REST) instead of cluttering up my controllers or overriding every model accessor that I use (is there a way to override them all easily?). Perhaps the best solution lies here.

It appears all of the built in methods like all, find, first, and last call **apply_finder_options** (and then **where**), but the dynamically created finders (find_by_name, etc) call **find_dynamic_match** which eventually calls **where**. This is what lead me to the **to_a** method on the relation, since it is common and called when the query is actually executed, and not just when building a relation before a query is executed. However getting this low level in into Rails makes me uncomfortable.

It seems like my problem shouldn't be an uncommon one, so perhaps my approach is wrong?

FYI, I'm new to rails and ruby. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly advise against using a low-level hook in place of explicit cache checking.  ActiveRecord has it's own caching mechanism, but if that isn't doing it for you and you need to build your own - use it *explicitly* before using ActiveRecord finders.  Hooks like these can make it very confusing to determine what is happening and why, and is not a recommended practice. Here is an example using a proxy model:

```
class CacheProxy
  attr_accessor :klass
  def initialize(klass)
    @klass = klass
  end

  def method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
    reload_if_necessary
    klass.send(method_id, *arguments, &block)
  end

  private
  def reload_if_necessary
    return unless needs_reload?
    # perform reload
  end

  def needs_reload?
    # determine if we need to reload the cache
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.proxy
    CacheProxy.new(self)
  end
end
```

Now you can even do `MyModel.proxy.find_by_first_name_and_last_name('John', 'Doe')`

Comment: I second PinnyM's concern and advice.  Why not use memcached?  Assuming your other REST APIs can access the new stuff you propose to put in the database, so can they access the stuff you put in memcached, right?  All they have to do is settle on a convention of how to name the cache keys (hint: use the methods built in to Rails caching :-), and when/how to invalidate them, and then instead of putting more load on the database, you're using memory.  The synchronization of multiple apps against the same database gives me the willies :-)

Comment: I'm basically looking for a way to populate my tables with new data before returning the data. I do currently have it refreshing in my controllers after a timeout, but I was hoping for a more centralized place to do it than in each of my controller methods.

Comment: So create a module that does this and include it in each of your models.  Or perhaps use a single central 'clearinghouse' model to do this.  Either way, you can get the same functionality without hacking ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far @PinnyM, but can you elaborate a bit? What would be in this module? I'd like for it to be as transparent as possible to the controllers. I was overriding find, all, etc. Is this what you are referring to? According to the docs it says that all, first, etc are just convenience methods to find, but looking at the source that is not the case, which is why I was overriding them all manually. Is there a way to overide ALL of these methods easily? Since ruby creates them based on the model it is hard to catch them all  (find_by_first_name_and_last_name, etc) Thanks

Comment: It would depend on how you query/refresh your REST resource data.  Can you provide some code as you are using it now?  `find`, `all`, and `first` are simple enough to catch, but how do you plan to determine if the cache needs to be refreshed from the REST resource?  Also, the find_by_... finders don't actually exist anywhere, they are caught and parsed using a specialized method_missing handler.

Comment: @PinnyM: I've updated my question above with some more info. To answer you question though I'm currently just refreshing the data for a users after it is 3 minutes stale for that user. I'm using .maximum on updated_at from the model to determine how old the data is. Sorry I don't have access to the code at the moment. Also, perhaps I am thinking to hard about this. I can just override find, all, etc and just be careful to not use the dynamic methods. It just seems like there should be a better, more complete way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Added some (untested) code as a suggestion, does that work for you?